# How do you make a calculator in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I tried to make the prompt allow the user to input the equation. I want it to output the answer. I know that I did the code wrong, so can you guys help so I can make an equation output from the prompt? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Your options are to use [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) (not recommended) or write a parser for equations.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh The "not recommended" on `eval` needs some qualification. Yes, for say a web-service that is subject to untrusted input you should probably *not* use `eval`. But for a script running on a local machine, where the user already has full access to Python, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple start.

```
from __future__ import division # 4/3 gives 1.0 without this
import math
# operators you can use:
#    "(", ")", "*", "/", "+", "-"
#    "math.sin()", "math.cos()", "math.tan()", "math.pi"
#    "**"
while True:
    result = eval(raw_input("Enter equation: ")) 
    result = float(result)
    print "result = " + str(result)
#
# (4+2)/3 = 2.0
# 3*7 = 21.0
# 2+(3-1) = 4.0
# math.sin(0) = 0.0
# math.cos(0) = 1.0
# math.asin(0) = 0.0
# math.acos(0) = 1.57079632679
# math.pi = 3.14159265359
# 2**2 = 4.0
# 9**0.5 = 3.0
```